# Update Form2 object from Form1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, richtextbox

I have code below that works when updating an object in Form1, from a second form. However it doesn't work the other way around when trying to update an object in Form2 from Form1?

Form 2 code;

```
   namespace testProject
{
    public partial class comPortWindow : Form
    {
        public static comPortWindow form = null;

        public comPortWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void comportLogText(String text)
        {
            if (form != null)
                form.updateRichTextBox1(text);
        }

        private void updateRichTextBox1(String text)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = text + " : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "\r\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 1 code;

```
comPortWindow comPortWindow = new comPortWindow();
comPortWindow.Show();
comPortWindow.comportLogText("hello");
```

Shows form 2 but no test appears in the rich text box.

Works the other way around, so maybe something to do with Form2 not being present when Form1 starts.

Comment: Hi. Don't think so since my code works updating Form1 objects from form2 i.e. other way around. It doesn't work from Form1 to another form

Comment: `public static comPortWindow form = null;` what is this for, its probably your issue, there is no need i can see for this

Comment: The constructor of comPortWindow is broken.  It forgets to update the `form` variable and forgets to throw an exception when it isn't null.  FormClosed is required to set it back to null.

Comment: Why not just change to the following, `public void comportLogText(String text)`  and remove the `form` stuff from your code, everything would jsut work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form 2 Code:

```
public partial class comPortWindow : Form
{

    public comPortWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void comportLogText(string text)
    {
            updateRichTextBox1(text);
    }

    private void updateRichTextBox1(string text)
    {
        richTextBox2.Text = text + " : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "\r\n" + richTextBox2.Text;
        richTextBox2.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

Form 1 Code:

```
    comPortWindow comPortWindow = new comPortWindow();
    comPortWindow.Show();
    comPortWindow.comportLogText("hello");
```

[image]